# bootable image on a USB partition

Tags: partitioning, usb

Why can't you select a partition on a thumb drive, instead of having to use the entire thumb drive when creating a bootable thumb drive?

Thanx!

Comment: You can with Ubuntu and grub2's loopmount command to directly boot an ISO. You used to be able to directly extract an ISO for UEFI boot into a FAT32 partition. FAT32 has a max of 4GB and does not support links. So Windows went and made .win over 4GB and Ubuntu added links. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c More examples: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

Comment: See also [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/isoboot) with a 'do it yourself' method helped by a compressed iso file, that sets up a grub boot system for UEFI and BIOS mode.

Comment: How to convert unused space on an ISO9660 Live install USB to NTFS space that both Linux and Windows can use, quick and easy: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198035/add-ntfs-data-partition-to-startup-disk-creator-usb-install