# Can we put files other than bootable files in a bootable flash Drive?

Tags: live-usb

I want to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. I have a 128GB pendrive and I have uploaded the .iso file of Ubuntu using Rufus. My pendrive has a whole lot of extra space left. Can I put some other files (like some .py files and some pdfs)in the bootable drive (for accessing it later in Ubuntu)and still be able to Dual boot safely ?

Comment: Read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/558182/put-more-things-on-a-bootable-flash-drive).

Comment: I suggest that you create a **persistent** live drive with [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) or an **installed** system (like a system installed into an internal drive) according to [**this link**](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447539&p=13974203#post13974203) to a post in the Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: I should add to my previous comment: If you have no running Ubuntu system yet, only Windows, you can use **Rufus** to create a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (but not 18.04.x LTS) and/or Rufus + 7-zip to create an installed system according to that link to a post in the Ubuntu Forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bootable USB Tool Data Files Storage

Data storage space depends on the Bootable USB tool used.

**Mkusb** will create a NTFS partition that can be used by Linux and Windows for Data storage. The partition can be reformatted as FAT32 using GParted so Apple can also use it.

**Rufus and UNetbootin** put their files on a FAT32 partition that can be used by Linux Windows and Apple for data. Putting data in it's own folder is recommended so it doesn't get mixed up with system files. When the USB is booted the data can be found in the cdrom folder. Data in the casper-rw/writable persistence partition/file is not accessible to Windows or Apple.

**Etcher, Startup Disk Creator, dd, Disks, etc,** drives can be easily modified so that unused space can be used for data, In Terminal run: `sudo mkfs.ntfs -f -L data /dev/sdx3`The drive must be booted at least once before making this conversion. For details see: [Add NTFS Data Partition to Startup Disk Creator USB Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198035/add-ntfs-data-partition-to-startup-disk-creator-usb-install)

Comment: I have already upvoted this answer, but found something that I would add for cloned drives. The command line `sudo mkfs.ntfs -f -L data /dev/sdx3` does not work on a virgin drive, because there is no partition `/dev/sdx3`. But if you boot into it (live) and the version is 19.10 or newer, the partition will be created, and after that, the command line will work (and convert the file system from ext4 to NTFS). mkusb-plug can do the same thing in a safe way, but your command line method is probably more attractive for many users, who have already created a live drive.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't modify the pendrive by resizing partitions then you are safe to add files to the existing partitions without any issues.