# Accessing Persistent USB files

Tags: windows, live-usb

How would you access files that are on a persistent live USB install made using mkusb? I want to transfer files from an Ubuntu live USB to a Windows PC; is this possible at all? I do not currently have an live USB with data that is important to transfer right now, so any solutions will be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Windows does not read EXT partitions, which I assume mksub creates (I'm not sure of that). You would have to install a special software or move the files to a device with FAT or NTFS partitions.

Comment: You can format your USB with vFAT. This filesystem can be read by Linux **and** Windows.

Comment: I think maybe you mean exFAT.  If you're on an older Ubuntu release with a kernel before 5.4, you'll need `exfat-fuse`and `exfat-utils` packages to read and write to exFAT from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Transfering Persistent mkusb Files Ubuntu to Windows

Mkusb can create a drive with a Persistent ext4 partition labeled **casper-rw** or **writable**.

It can also create a NTFS partition named **usbdata**.

The casper-rw or writable partition is only accessible if a program like **DiskInternals Linux Reader** in installed. The basic version is a Free program available from https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/.

I have tried Linux Reader and it allowed me to read/copy everything on the Linux disk including home folder, which is located in the upper folder of the persistence partition.

The usbdata partition is accessible to Linux and Windows with out any additional programs. If Apple is included in the equation the NTFS partition can be formatted to FAT32 without any problem.

For data access on other Bootable USB systems see: [Can we put files other than bootable files in a bootable flash Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261893/can-we-put-files-other-than-bootable-files-in-a-bootable-flash-drive/1261906#1261906)