# Can we use EtchDroid to create Ubuntu installation media?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

Let's say that I don't have any PC working in my home right now and I cannot borrow someone else's PC as well. I only have an Android smartphone (which is not rooted), pendrive and micro USB to USB-A converter. I want to create an Ubuntu installation media only using the aforementioned things. I found out an app named [EtchDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.depau.etchdroid) in Google Play Store. Can we use EtchDroid to create Ubuntu installation media and how good is the installation media when created using EtchDroid? Is it almost the same as using Rufus or some other software?

I also want to know if I can use an micro SD card for creating an installation media instead of a pendrive.

Comment: I would ask  android users this if I was you. You wanting to burn Ubuntu to an Micro SD is fine but you are limiting yourself by restricting yourself to android. Only thing of interest: Micro SD Linux installs need to be FAT. No exFat or NTFS. I would give up on this idea as you will need a windows system and 3rd party software to do that for a Micro SD 32Gb or larger.

Comment: Yes, you can install Ubuntu using a smartphone. The method on this page worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-installing-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media You can also use MP3 players or a digital camera or just about anything with a SD card

Answer (score 8):

### EtchDroid to create Ubuntu installation media

EtchDroid sounds like it meets your requirements and has a good rating and sounds safe. I gave EtchDroid a trial and had good results.

- Downloaded and installed EtchDroid from the Google Play Store.
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.depau.etchdroid&hl=en
- Connected USB flash drive using micro USB to USB-A converter.
- Started EtchDroid and selected "Write raw image or ISO".

  [image]
- Selected the Ubuntu ISO file

  [image]
- Selected the target USB from upper right on the screen:

  [image]
- And clicked the write icon on the lower right.

  [image]

At first I thought nothing had happened but when I returned later I found that the USB was ready for a Live boot or Install.

There are similar apps that flash image files to USB using Windows including Etcher and Win32DiskImager, and from Ubuntu including Etcher, Startup Disk Creator and Gnome-Disks. This is a handy free app to have on your phone.

My only complaint is that this app will not write to an internal SD card, but I understand that this is a safety feature.

If you successfully try this app, please leave an answer to your own question here. I am sure many people would be interested.

Comment: I did install Ubuntu in my PC using this method couple of months ago. But now I tried using it as live media, and I failed. I tried rewriting the image many times. The installation media didn't work properly. I'm not sure if it's because of EtchDroid or because of me formatting the pendrive so many times.

Comment: @technastic_tc: I restarted the process about a dozen times because I thought It was not working. I then started it again and went for dinner, when I returned the USB was flashed and the Live install worked. I think it takes a while. I will try it again a few more times. I think you need to start with a USB freshly formatted FAT32.

Comment: @technastic_tc: If you plan on using the drive as Live media you might be interested in formatting the left over space on the drive as a NTFS data partition, See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198035/add-ntfs-data-partition-to-startup-disk-creator-usb-install . You can also boot using F6 and The word `persistent` to make the session Persistent.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to format a pendrive as NTFS in Android . There have been many instances when the installation medium just gets stuck (mostly during the checking files stage). What's the most appropriate thing to do during such instances? Reboot using Ctrl+Alt+Del doesn't work. I should press the restart button ‍♂️. Is it safe for the pendrive? BTW, I've formatted the pendrive so many times using Android. BTW, what's `persistent`?

Comment: Oops, Perhaps FAT32 is better: `sudo mkfs.vfat -f -L data /dev/sdxy`. I press the restart button when experimenting and have not bricked a drive yet. Best to wait until the drive light is not flickering.

Comment: My PC is not working. So I don't think I can execute the command which you've typed. What do you mean by 'drive light'?

Comment: Most of my Thumb drives have a little light that goes on when they are active.

Comment: My pendrive doesn't have any such light  :-\ So I guess my only option is pressing the reboot button.

Comment: It is recommended to do a long format occasionally, (zero the drive). They seem to run a little better afterwards.

Comment: Hey @C.S.Cameron. Let's chat here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113287/room-for-technastic-tc-and-c-s-cameron