# Is it possible to download Ubuntu on my android device and then install it on my computer using a USB cabel?

Tags: system-installation

Could you tell me if it is somehow possible to download Ubuntu on my android device and then install it on my old desktop computer, which is operated by Windows XP and has no Wi-Fi driver or internet connection, using a USB cabel?

Comment: Have a look at DriveDroid or EtchDroid https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media and  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274361/can-we-use-etchdroid-to-create-ubuntu-installation-media/1274545#1274545