# How to burn the iso file to a micro sd card on my android phone

Tags: android, iso, sd-card, phone, burner

I've ben trying to find a tutorial online to help me burn a ubuntu iso image to my sd card connected to my android phone but I can't find anything for it not even an app. I was wondering if you could recommend or help me find one so I can burn my sd card without having to buy a adapter

Comment: You may need a computer.

Comment: It is usually better to use a PC for this.  If trying to use/install Ubuntu onto your phone, did you already check if you can install Ubuntu on that phone, some you can, a lot you can't?  Some android forums might have better ideas, google should find them, and might already have an answer.

Comment: I assume you want to make a Ubuntu install USB. Etchdroid might work, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274545/43926

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we use EtchDroid to create Ubuntu installation media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274361/can-we-use-etchdroid-to-create-ubuntu-installation-media)

Comment: its about doing something on android, not ubuntu