# New instance every time while using ubuntu 20.04 in a bootable pendrive

Tags: live-usb, 20.04, bug-reporting, data-loss

I just installed ubuntu 20.04 in bootable pendrive.I wanted to use ubuntu in bootable pendrive,as my laptop has no free space in harddisk.Whenever i boot **ubuntu 20.04 using bootable pendrive** it shows checking file system everytime,after some time it shows me the installation window with two options (Try Ubuntu,Install Ubuntu).So i had to click on try ubuntu every time.Everytime the screen shows up and when i click **Try ubuntu** it once again shows the manufacturer logo and loads as new desktop each time and the files i stored in it and the update i made to the sofware is no more.I tried it out in different pendrive too.
please help to solve the issue that **it shows new setup everytime i turn on my laptop and the files in it and the changes i made gets erased**

Comment: You are using the install media, used to install a system. It allows you to try the system (everything will be saved to memory; lost on reboot which can be really handy!) and do installations. It's a 'live' system meaning unless you purposely save files to permanent storage, everything saved to "/" (memory) is lost on shutdown/reboot.  You need to write it with persistence (so it remains) which is **not** the default.

Comment: Maybe helpful -  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203053/live-ubuntu-usb-with-persistent-storage-using-mkusb  or probably better  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: Full install vs Persistent install: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235480/i-want-to-make-a-portable-version-of-linux-ubuntu/1235490#1235490

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the Live USB version of Ubuntu doesn't let you save your data from previous sessions. As the option "Try Ubuntu" implies, that is only for testing Ubuntu. If you want to install Ubuntu on that pendrive properly, you can follow [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-real-ubuntu-os-usb-drive/) tutorial (or any number of similar tutorials), but I'd personally recommend a lighter OS for a pendrive, especially if said drive is on the smaller side.

Comment: The method you point to works in BIOS mode only, most computers nowadays are UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to build a live USB with some data persistence. If your main OS is Windows you can do that with Rufus or UnetBootin, if you are on Linux check [Andrei Bratosin's earlier comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246747/1067324). However keep in mind that while this would work, it would hardly be suitable for everyday use. USB drives are slow for this kind of use case. If you want to get a better experience consider purchasing a cheap 128GB SSD and an external USB 3.0 enclosure, these could be found perhaps even for less than $30 or your regional equivalent. You can then install the OS on that disk and boot from it whenever you like, speeds are shockingly close to SATA3 SSDs and the overall experience is great.