# Creating/editing a bootable usb with your own applications (like a hirens boot)

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

Can you help me with my problems?

i want to make a bootable usb image of a ubuntu system.
point is, i want to use a USB (witch you normaly can install ubuntu from) to boot from with some special applications i need. i know you can use a ubuntu stick and click on "try ubuntu" to work from it.
only  problem is:
you can install some apps to use it. but everytime you power off the pc you need to reinstall it.

i want to change or use a backup to make a usable usb like a hirens boot to change the image, so i can use all the tools i need without reinstalling it every single time.
i've been stuck for some months now. can anybody help?

im not much of a programmer, although im learning it.
anybody have an idea or who can help me to achieve my goal.

Also i already used squashfs files to edit it, but im not reallly understanding what i have to change.
you can mount en unsquash the filesystem. and edit that, but it havent been succesfull for me. it didnt work everytime i tried

just to be clear again, goal:

create my own bootable ubuntu from an USB, with special application/tools of my or your (if anybody else wanna use it) needs.

I hope you guys/gals can help me.

S. Stratmann

Comment: Why not use a *live* system with persistence (ie. you can install applications, updates & they'll be there when you next use the *live* media)?   You can also install to a thumb-drive (which achieves the same thing (faster, no squash/cow), though this is a little more work, esp. for some releases).

Comment: Thank you for your responds, live media, thats what i need. how do you edit it? because you get a squashfs file, i can unsquash it, how do you install apps on that file system. for example chrome browser? you get an .deb file i can exacute it, but i cant seem to get t working. or am i in the wrong direction?

Comment: I use `mkusb` to create my *live* media with persistence, Ubuntu wiki page on persistence can be read at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent though it's covered here in questions too, eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203053/live-ubuntu-usb-with-persistent-storage-using-mkusb

Comment: Have a look at using an image file for making a custom installation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution The resulting USB can be **Persistent** or a **Full install**.

Comment: Hey Guys, i have a little question more. i have created it with mkusb, i used the ubuntu donwload. only he tells me right before installing everything, the iso you use is not debian nor ubuntu.  is that a common issue or could i rather use another image? i used the original image.

Comment: I have tried quite a few non Debian based OS with mkusb. most of them have worked. Give it a try, worst that can happen is that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A very detailed procedure on how to create a custom live CD is [available on Github](https://github.com/mvallim/live-custom-ubuntu-from-scratch). It shows how to set up a chroot eenvironmemnt, in which you configure and build your live system, and how to create a bootable ISO of it.

There used to be software, [Ubuntu Kit Customization](http://uck.sourceforge.net/) kit. This made it a very easy task. Unfortunately, that project was discontinued.