# What is the correct way to create a Persistent Ubuntu 20.04 Usb?

Tags: software-installation, live-usb, 20.04, persistence

I want to create a persistent Ubuntu 20.04 on my 8GB USB stick. Currently I have both windows and ubuntu as base Os. Better with windows.

Comment: Yes, the same way for 19.10 and newer versions :-)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Good question. 20.04 is taking up more space than 18.04. Extracting the ISO to USB require a root partition of almost 3GB. This leaves a little over four GB for a persistent partition, which is quickly filled up, and a NTFS partition. 20.04 persistent install also has a major problem with an unsolicited disk check that runs every boot and is difficult to stop.

Comment: It works with your 8 GB USB stick, but it would be a major step forward to get a fast USB 3 stick with at least 16 GB, even better with 32 GB. The following link discusses speed and size of USB sticks, which makes a difference for a persistent live system: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/pre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/pre). With a big and fast USB 3 drive, it is also a good idea to install Ubuntu like you install it into an internal drive (but into the USB drive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the current version of

- [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) in Windows and
- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Ubuntu.

These tools can create persistent live drives from the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS iso file. See more details at the following link and links from it,

- [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)

You can also extract and clone a compressed image file directly according to the following link,

- [Xubuntu Core 20.04 LTS with mkusb 12.4.5 (mkusb-dus and mkusb-plug)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Xubuntu_Core_20.04_LTS_with_mkusb_12.4.5_.28mkusb-dus_and_mkusb-plug.29)

Comment: Is it the same way as installing 19.10 , Or weather there is any new method of doing it.

Comment: @Tylore, Yes, you can use the same methods that work with 19.10 also with 20.04 LTS :-)

Comment: Is there any difference in creating this with rufus and mkusb ? Which is better ?

Comment: @Tylore, Rufus works in Windows. mkusb works in Ubuntu and Debian linux. The results (the persistent live systems) are not exactly the same, but rather similar. The persistent live systems work i similar ways. Please notice also that the systems made by mkusb-dus and mkusb-plug are also different from each other. *If you wish, you can try all these methods and select the one that you like best.* Maybe use the method that is most convenient for you because I think the persistent live systems should work well in all cases. If you want the extra `usbdata` partition with NTFS, use mkusb-dus.