# How to store downloaded data in bootable usb ubuntu 20.04 while trying it without installing

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I have ubuntu in my 16 gb usb. I don't have hard disk so only way I can use Ubuntu is from live session
I downloaded some data from internet and there is no option to move it to usb.

1. How can I paste in it because otherwise it will be gone next time after power off?
2. Is there any better way to use Ubuntu from usb other than "try ubuntu" without installing?

Im a noob so please try to explain in simple methods.

Comment: You could try tails OS. It is similar to Ubuntu in many aspects, and it can store data. Just read before hand how to store data.

Comment: Can store data to another USB stick/SD card.  Can also install Ubuntu to a bigger USB stick from your live USB, if handy.  Does not need to install on hard drive.  Don't install on a USB stick with data on it, or you will lose data.

Comment: You want persistence.  See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: I use network storage (NFS) when using a *live* system. The / file system is in memory, and of limited size, so I avoid writing there & just `mount` a network share & write there (I use NFS, but SaMBa (or CIFS) could be used also..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/q/397481/)

Answer (score 0):

The installer LiveUSB is READ-ONLY.

- You cannot save data to the USB stick, sorry.
- Advice: Save it to someplace online before you end your session.

It is possible to create a writable partition to the USB stick (we call that *persistence*.) However, that must be done when creating the USB installer on the stick. After booting from the USB stick is much too late.

Answer (score 0):

### Full Install to USB

If you do a Full install to USB It will work the same as an Install to Hard Disk, (except a little slower). The following will leave a little space left over on your disk for data.

### Quick Method for Making Full Install of Ubuntu to USB.

The creator of **mkusb** has been perfecting the use of image files for creating Full installs of Ubuntu on USB. Download Image file is 1.5GB, not 15GB.

- Download https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-07_with-proposed.img.xz
- Decompress file using 7Zip.
- Flash to USB using Rufus, Etcher, Image Writer, etc.
- Password is "changeme", Change it.

MD5Sum can be found here: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/md5sum.txt.asc