# Is there a complete USB bootable iso available

Tags: usb, network-manager, application-development, iso, netgear

I need a complete USB bootable iso to be able to set up my computer with only Wifi available.. Netgear USB wifi.
There seems to be missing a lot in the basic USB iso installation to be able to get to developer level to be able to install drivers for the Netgear AC1200 USB wifi device.. All instructions i found suppose a working network "get, apt, install, make" to perform installation of a/this Wifi network device.

Is there such complete iso for the rufus available?

BR
HO

Comment: Try making a persistent live USB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: I think the OPs problem is getting network drivers without having a network to download them for his Netgear AC1200 USB wifi device.

Comment: I wonder why people don't use a phone for it and complain that they need a driver to connect to the internet.

Comment: The AC1200 is a notoriously incompatible chipset...and that's the manufacturer's fault. If your vendor claimed "Linux compatible," that's a flat lie. Hold the vendor and manufacturer accountable for duping you by returning the shoddy hardware. Purchase real Linux-friendly hardware from a reputable vendor instead...and make sure they have a generous return policy

Comment: Ok . Thankyou.. I will stop trying to install the AC1200. I went for a BrosTrend 1200 Mbps Linux USB instead..

Answer (score 0):

There is no ISO that includes all kind of 3-rd party drivers.

You can always install using a standard Ubuntu ISO, then connect your phone as a USB modem and install any drivers you need.