# ubuntu live usb with preinstall application

Tags: xubuntu

i created a live USB , and i use try ubuntu when boot.
i do not want to save any data, but few applications and files need to be preinstalled when boot.

1. telegram app
2. signal app
3. google chrome browser
4. few favorite web link

how to do that? thanks awesome ubuntu expert.

Comment: You can make a *persistent* live drive. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10) and links from it.

Comment: thanks reply. will persistent live drive save my cookies and chat record?

Comment: Yes, it you don't want that, you can make a 'respin', but it is much more complicated: create your own live system with the tools that you want. An alternative could be to create separate partitions labeled `casper-rw` and `home-rw`, and delete the content of `home-rw` after each working session. Cookies and chat records should reside in your home directory, which is stored in the partition `home-rw`, if there is such a partition.