# Would Canonical consider adding smartctl and gsmartcontrol to "try ubuntu"?

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, canonical, smart

In other distributions (names redacted to protect the guilty) the S.M.A.R.T tools are included in so-called recovery images.  Most of the tools useful to deal with hard disk problems are already in the TryUbuntu image.  Missing are the S.M.A.R.T tools "smartctl" and "gsmartcontrol".

During a troubleshooting session, I was able to copy smartctl(8) to a thumb drive formatted for EXT4, and was able to execute it to find my problem.  I know this is not everyone's cup of tea, and most of the time one doesn't need it...until one does.  Particularly if one can't boot one's system.

Partition management and mkfs are there; adding smartctl(8) would be a help.  gsmartcontrol(8) is the GUI front end for smartctl(8).

Comment: GNOME Disks is preinstalled already. If you plan data recovery - use special livecds like Systemrescuecd.

Comment: You can create a [**persistent live drive**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10) and install your favourite application programs (`smartctl` and some other tools), and they will persist past shutdown and reboot. - But I agree with N0rbert that it is a good idea to use some special live drives dedicated for rescue actions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic, as this is a user-support site and not the Ubuntu bug tracking site (launchpad.net) where bug reports & feature requests should be made.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs