# Cant click next on the installation of Lubuntu 22.10

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb

Im trying to make a live usb stick with persistent storage, but i cant click next on the lubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

You create a *live* system with persistence using a ISO writing tool that can create it.

The Lubuntu `calamares` install will make a full install, and will not create a *live* system as it's an installer, not a ISO writer (*ISO writing software is used to create *live* systems with or without persistence*).

If you've not met the requirements for a dialog in `calamares`, the *NEXT* button will not show, this is by design.

You provided no clear indication of which screen you're using (*via link to page etc*) but as I believe you're trying to do something the `calamares` installer isn't designed for, a *unclickable* *NEXT* button could have been expected.

- Calamares docs can be read here - https://calamares.io/docs/users-guide/
- Lubuntu's manual (*for 23.04 currently*) can be read here - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html
- If I wanted to create a Lubuntu *live* system with persistence, I'd use `mkusb` to create the system, refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent for more details.  Other writing tools exist though too.

Comment: I note @sudodus has answered a post on our discourse (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/create-persistent-usb-with-manual-install/1498) and points to an answer he gave on this site - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10  so this may be worth a look; even duplicate for other close-voters too !!

Comment: I wrote this answer as mostly I was too wordy/long for a comment.. If my understanding of what the OP wants is correct, there is no better answer.. as we don't know the OS the OP used to create the thumb-drive, thus sudodus' answer in my last comment may not be helpful... we don't have enough details for more than what I've provided here I believe.

Comment: I don't know much about linux yet so I can't do hard stuff :(

Comment: Key is you are using an install (*which installs the full system*) to write an ISO to thumb-drive which isn't its drive. You want a *live* (ie. uninstalled system) so want it before it's installed, but want persistence added to your *live* system. That is done via the software that writes an ISO to media (usually called *writer* or *burner* and never *installer).  This isn't GNU/Linux stuff; just IT/tech stuff as its the ~same terms with windows/mac/BSD & other OSes; but hey it's still 'new' until we've done it a few times. Keep trying.